# ¿Cómo puedo lograr forma de flecha en un botón?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, botón

[image: Imagen]

Necesito darle forma al botón tal y como se muestra en la imagen, ¿cómo podría hacerlo!?

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Desde" type="text" id="desde"/>
        <span id="clickdesde" class="input-group-btn">
            <button style="border-radius: 2px" class="form-control btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>                                            
        </span>
    </div>                                         
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Hasta" type="text" id="hasta"/>
        <span id="clickhasta" class="input-group-btn">
            <button style="border-radius: 2px" class="form-control btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>                                            
        </span>
    </div>                                         
</div>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, qué has intentado hasta ahora? Tienes algo de código que nos puedas mostrar?

Comment: Si, lo acabo de agregar.

Comment: existe una libreria llamada semantic-ui podrias basarte de ellos como lo hacen

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes disponible esta herramienta online [www.cssarrowplease.com](http://www.cssarrowplease.com/)

Funciona bastante bien para obtener una base y posteriormente ajustar el código a tus necesidades.

Como información extra, para los input de tipo fecha tienes esta librería
[flatpickr.js.org](https://flatpickr.js.org/) puede que también te resulte útil.

Un saludo

```css
.input-group button{
  position: relative;
}

.input-group button::after{
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-right-color: #28a745;
  border-width:8px;
  margin-top:-8px;
  z-index:3
}

.input-group button:hover{
  background: #28a745;
  border-color:#28a745;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Desde" type="text" id="desde"/>
      <span id="clickdesde" class="input-group-btn">
        <button style="border-radius: 2px" class="form-control btn btn-success">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </button>                                            
      </span>
    </div>                                         
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Hasta" type="text" id="hasta"/>
      <span id="clickhasta" class="input-group-btn">
        <button style="border-radius: 2px" class="form-control btn btn-success">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </button>                                            
      </span>
    </div>                                         
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar el psudoelemento `::before` y hacer una flecha usando los bordes:

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-group-btn {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group-btn::before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #28a745;
  top: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.input-group-btn:hover::before {
  content: "";
  border-right-color: #218838;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Desde" type="text" id="desde" />
      <span id="clickdesde" class="input-group-btn">
      <button style="border-radius: 2px" class="form-control btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Hasta" type="text" id="hasta" />
      <span id="clickhasta" class="input-group-btn">
      <button style="border-radius: 2px" class="form-control btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```